# What is the difference between "저는 친구에게 전화했어요" (don't use 아/어/여 주다) and "저는 친구에게 전화해 줬어요" (use 아/어/여 주다)?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I think they have the same meaning as "I called my friend". A similar example is:

> "선생님이 학생들에게 한국어를 가르치셨어요"

and

> "선생님이 학생들에게 한국어를 가르쳐 주셨어요".

They all mean "the teacher teaches the students", right? If they all mean the same, how do I know when should I use 아/어 주다 (such as "저는 친구에게 전화해 줬어요" and "선생님이 학생들에게 한국어를 가르쳐 주셨어요"), and when shouldn't I use this structure?

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=109598)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-해 주다 normally means you do something *as a favor* (it doesn't have to be grandiose - just any act that benefits someone else).

For example:

> 내일 수업 취소된 거 민주는 알아? Does Minjoo know that tomorrow's class is canceled?
>
> 응, 내가 방금 **전화해 줬어**. Yes, I just called her.

Here, you're calling her to let her know that the class is canceled - you're doing it for Minjoo's sake, so "전화해 줬어" is appropriate.  (You can also say "전화했어" as well - it makes no assumptions about who benefits from what.)

On the other hand:

> 집에 도착했더니 택시비가 없어서, 할 수 없이 자는 누나에게 **전화했다**.
>
> I arrived home and realized that I didn't have any money to pay the taxi driver, so I had to call my sleeping sister.

Here, you made the phone call for your own sake (you needed money) - so you can't use "전화해 줬다" here.

Answer (score 3):

"해 주다" is a composition of "하다" and "주다". Both of "하다" and "해 주다" have a similar meaning (so using it interchangeably will not cause confusion of meaning in usual). However, they have a different nuance.

According to [the answer of the National Institute of Korean Language](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=109598), "주다" in "해 주다" means

> 앞 동사의 행위가 다른 사람의 행위에 영향을 미침을 나타내는 말
>
> *(verb + 주다 means) the action by verb affects the other's act.*

Hence "해 주다" means it affects the other one by doing something (implied by the verb "하다".)

Let me give you some examples. In the case of

- 선생님이 학생들에게 한국어를 가르쳤어요

just means a teacher teaches the students Korean. However,

- 선생님이 학생들에게 한국어를 가르쳐 줬어요

means not only the teacher teaches Korean, but also the students (possibly) know Korean as a result of teaching.

"해 주다" sometimes insinuates the speaker's seeming care. (More appropriate word for it would be [시혜성](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/4cd547ac93154d5f9fcf3d71a0973c04), but I do not know the exact counterpart of it in English.) For example.

- 친구에게 전화했어요

means no more than "I called to my friend." However,

- 친구에게 전화해 줬어요

means not only you called a friend, but you could also have a reason to call a friend (e.g., your friend is seriously injured, so you called a friend to check their status.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the word 시혜성. I would just add that their past definition was easier to understand. It was 다른 사람을 위하여 어떤 행동을 함을 나타내는 말 ("a word used to show that one does it for another person") several years ago. They changed it to an obscure definition without leaving any accounts in the dictionary. I assume that this was because 주다 is used [not only with positive connotations (showing kindness or taking action in sympathy) but also with negative undertones (showing authority, false compassion, etc.)](https://thepin.ch/think/mhsLi/ohj-column-3).